# Idiom for the impossibility of using the same tool/method for different tasks

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I'm looking for an idiom (if there is one) which captures the following meaning: trying to do two things with the same tool will never work, since every task requires its own tool.

It is similar to "if the only tool you have is a hammer, to treat everything as if it were a nail", but this has the emphasis of over-reliance on one tool. Rather, I'm looking for something that expresses the futility of trying to find a single solution for two different problems.

Comment: "If you can dodge a wrench, you can dodge a ball!" -  Patches O'Houlihan

Comment: *Never bring a knife to a gunfight*.

Comment: *Using words to describe magic is like using a screwdriver to cut roast beef.*
– Tom Robbins

Comment: THE question is, "the futility of trying to find a single solution for two different problems."  This must be known since it isn't impossible to find single solutions.  Knowing that, further trying would be foolish; it would be futile.  I don't think answers are addressing that question.  Maybe I've read it incorrectly.  Wouldn't be the first time.

Answer (score 1):

- There's a saying that goes, ***[If you run after two hares, you will catch neither.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/If+you+run+after+two+hares,+you+will+catch+neither)***

  > *(Prov.)* You cannot do two things successfully at the same time.

  [The Free Dictionary]
- There's also this saying - "***[have your cake and eat it too](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+cake+and+eat+it+too)***"

  > to do or get two good things at the same time

  [The Free Dictionary]

  **Usage:**

  > "Trying to solve two different problems with the same tactic is like having your cake and eating it too. You simply can't."
- Or you could simply say that it is foolish to expect a ***[panacea](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/panacea)*** every time you face problems.  It's not an idiom per se but conveys what you intend well.

  > something that will ​solve all ​problems

  [Cambridge Dictionaries Online]